# What Character Encoding is this? [Example Character to Int value provided]

Tags: character-encoding

I is represented as 21321 when printed as an Integer.

The data is coming from a device into a Delphi DLL and being passed to me to write out.  However, it does not sit well with Delphi's Ansi string conversions.

I just need to know possible character encodings this may be, so I can begin to identify how to convert it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number 21321 is 5349 in hexadecimal, and interpreted a 8-bit values, 53 and 49 are the ASCII codes for the Latin letters “S” and “I.” So my guess is that the data is actually “SI” in ASCII or some compatible encoding.

It is difficult to imagine any encoding where “I” would be 5349 hexadecimal, so this is about something else than just an unknown encoding.